# Why strange declaration of CCLayer in cocos2d?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I have a class GameScene, during init of which I make a scene and attach a child to it - a layer. I noticed strange code for it:

```
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    CCLayer *layer = [GameScene node];
    [scene addChild:layer];
```

Why not do this instead?

```
CCLayer *layer = [CCLayer node];
```

This doesn't add to readability or am I missing something fundamental here? Also, why not use alloc init at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[CCNode node];
```

is a static (class) method. It automatically calls `[[[self alloc] init] autorelease];`

Any CCNode subclass can be initialized using this static initializer. It is basically for convenience and is really not needed. (Although, like I said, it is nice to have).

Class methods use the "+" sign and instance methods use the "-" sign. Class methods are like static methods in Java. They can be called without creating an instance of that class.
It could look like this: `[YourClass doSomething]; //Doesn't need an instance of YourClass`

Instance methods need an instance of their class to be able to be run. This would look like:

```
YourClass *yClass = [[YourClass alloc] init];
[yClass doSomethingElse]; //Needs an instance of YourClass
```

I haven't looked, but I assume the `node` method looks something like this:

```
+ (CCNode*)node {
    return [[[self alloc] init] autorelease];
}
```

The odd declaration just returns a scene (initialized with a static initializer) with your custom layer as a child, that the CCDirector can then use and display.

EDIT: something I feel would add clarity.

The strange declaration is just a static initializer `+ (CCScene*)scene` which returns a scene.